# GLKView snapshot returning bad colors

Tags: ios, glkview

I'm doing some fun shader stuff, but when I call snapshot I get some strange coloring artifacts. In particular, it seems that the red channel is...stuck high, maybe?

```
UIImage* image = [(GLKView*)self.view snapshot];
```

Not sure what other code to show, because it doesn't matter if I then turn that into a JPEG and save it to the roll, or just display it in a UIImageView directly, it has a strange red tint.

Some slight chance that this question is also relevant, but it has no answers ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447265/how-to-avoid-shadows-over-the-glkview-object-in-ios

It ... actually seems to be fixed if I set the view's `drawableColorFormat` to `GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGB565` ... so ... could anyone explain why that might be?

Comment: Note to self: default is The default value is GLKViewDrawableColorFormat.RGBA8888. ... but there's the slightest chance that setting it to ANYTHING might be fixing it? Of course, this is all deprecated, now, so... mileage may vary.